# Varnish VCL backend hostname

Tags: backend, hostname, varnish-vcl

I can't set backend host = hostname (ex: example.com)

and port = protocol (http/https)!

```
backend default_proxy {
    .host = "example.com";
    .port = "http";
}
```

Version used: 6.0.1

Operating System and version: Centos 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more information, like an error message would have been useful. Usually this error comes from the fact that the domain name resolves to more than one IP. Try using the IP directly, or `vmod_goto` (but it's part of a commercial offer).